# Join() methods only transforme some arrays into string

Tags: javascript

Im trying to make a code to add the string "way" to the words that begin with a vowel, or add the word "ay" and the first letter of the word at the end of the string if the word begin with a consonant. I splited the words to see if the start with a consonant or a vowel , then add the "way" or "ay" with the first leter, and at last joined the array to show the resultant string. The problem is that the join only worked for the words that begin with vowel. How can i fix this?

the code:

```
function isVowel(c) {
  return ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].indexOf(c.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
}

function translatePigLatin(str) {

  str=str.split('');
  var firstLetter=str[0];

  if(isVowel(firstLetter)) str.push("way");

  else {    

     str.splice(0,1);
     str=str+firstLetter+"ay";

  }

  str= Array.prototype.join.call(str,"");
  alert(str);

  return str;
}

translatePigLatin("consonant");
```

Comment: So to be clear, when you pass in `consonant`, what do you expect to get back ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were adding with operator `+` to the array which can mess up the type, casting the array to a string. You should use `push` on an array to get the behaviour you seek.

```js
function isVowel(c) {
  return ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].indexOf(c.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
}

function translatePigLatin(str) {

  str=str.split('');
  var firstLetter=str[0];

  if(isVowel(firstLetter)){
   
    str.push("way");

  }else {    

     str.splice(0,1);
     str.push(firstLetter+"ay");

  }

  str= Array.prototype.join.call(str,"");
  alert(str);

  return str;
}

translatePigLatin("consonant");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you used string concatenation on an array and so the result wasn't something that `.join()` would work on. Instead you need to `.push()` into the array and then `.join()` the whole thing.

```
function isVowel(c) {
  return ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].indexOf(c.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
}

function translatePigLatin(str) {

  str = str.split('');
  var firstLetter = str[0];

  if(isVowel(firstLetter)) { 
    str.push("way") 
  } else {    
     str.splice(0,1);
     str.push('ay')
  }
  alert(str.join(''));
    return str.join('');
}

translatePigLatin("consonant");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this using a RegEx as shown in the sample.

```js
function Translate(inputWord) {
  if (/^[aeiou]/i.test(inputWord)) {
    return inputWord + "way";
  } else {
    return inputWord + inputWord.charAt(0) + "ay";
  }
}

console.log(Translate("consonant"));
console.log(Translate("apple"));
```